# How to use SIMD inside MonoDevelop (Unity)?

Tags: dll, mono, unity-game-engine, simd

Currently I'm creating a game in Unity, the programming is done in C#. Since the code is making heavy use of vectors and matrices, I would like to use Mono's SIMD-support. The only problem is that the MonoDevelop that Unity is using is a fork of the original Mono, so Mono.Simd.dll is not yet included. I thought, just download the dll and see if I can get it to work inside my version of MonoDevelop, but I can't find Mono.Simd.dll anywhere (I've downloaded recent versions of Mono and searched through them, nothing looks even remotely SIMD-related). So where can I find Mono.Simd.dll, and how do I get it to work inside MonoDevelop?

Additional info: Yes, I know GPU's would be even better at handling vectors and matrices but I can't use them for several reasons. Also, I'm working from a Mac (please, please, don't start a flamewar or anything. I know some of you think Windows might be better for developing, but I don't have a choice right now). I've read sources that say downloading a recent Mono-release should have Mono.Simd, but as I said, I can't find it. Could it be that something is (named) different inside Mac-releases?

Comment: Look in \Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0, it's there on my Unity version 3.5.

Comment: Basically Unity comes with it's own set of Vectors and Matrices functions. I'd be surprised if the Unity guys didn't optimize these. Plus they probably did optimize them for every target platform so you don't have to worry about this stuff working on mobile platforms, XBox, PS3 and whatnot.